# React.js - When authorizing on the site, if the data is incorrect, how can I get a response with a text error?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs, axios

I send data to API with email and password. API Ruby on Rails with library devise-token-auth

---

**signinform.js**

......................................................

```
onSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({errors: {}, isLoading: true});
this.props.userSignInRequest(this.state).then(
  () => {console.log('ok!')},
  ({resp}) => { console.log(resp.errors); }
);
```

}
.........................................................

**actions/signInActions.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export function userSignInRequest(userData){
  return dispatch => {
    return axios.post('/auth/sign_in', userData);
  }
}
```

If email or password are incorrect i get response:

```
{"errors":["Invalid login credentials. Please try again."]}
```

But console.log(resp.errors); display undefined. If i put `(resp) => { console.log(resp); }` I get in console:

**Error: Request failed with status code 401 at createError (createError.js?16d0:16) at settle (settle.js?db52:18) at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)**

How me get errors in console.log(resp);

Answer (score 3):

That is because the way you have written `resp` in argument. You have written resp in bracket  like `{resp}`. It means whenever any object will be passed to this function, `resp` will be equal to `resp` property of that object. But as the response only have `errors` property and no `resp` property, it shows undefined.

So to work with this you can do either

```
onSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({errors: {}, isLoading: true});
this.props.userSignInRequest(this.state).then(
  () => {console.log('ok!')},
  (resp) => { console.log(resp.errors); }
);
```

or

```
onSubmit(e){
e.preventDefault();
this.setState({errors: {}, isLoading: true});
this.props.userSignInRequest(this.state).then(
  () => {console.log('ok!')},
  ({errors}) => { console.log(errors); }
);
```

EDIT:

```
this.props.userSignInRequest(this.state).then(() =>{
    console.log('ok!')
}).catch((resp) => {
    console.log(resp.response.data);
}));
```

Comment: As an addition to this answer, here is a link on javascript destructuring 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Destructuring is what happens when you put braces around a javascript object.

Comment: hm.... i changed to `({errors}) => { console.log(errors); }`, display again undefined, but response in chrome console: ` {"errors":["Invalid login credentials. Please try again."]}`

Comment: Update your question with userSignInRequest function.

Comment: What is the returned http status code from the api??

Comment: Status Code:401 Unauthorized

Comment: The documentation of axios tells that when there is status code other then 2xx then the returned data will be available to resp.response.data . So try resp.response.data.errors.

Comment: A better way will be to directly do console.log(resp) and it will show where your returned data is available.

Comment: if without brackets, easy resp and console.log(resp) display: **Error: Request failed with status code 401
    at createError (createError.js?16d0:16)
    at settle (settle.js?db52:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js?ec6c:77)**